# How can I force a Vim command to run silently?

Tags: vim

I have some keymappings in my vimrc for moving entire lines up/down. For example,

```
nnoremap <D-J> :move .+1<CR>==
```

moves a line down (swapping with the line below it). It echoes the command, `:move .+1`, at the command line, and I'd like to silence that. I've tried

```
nnoremap <silent> ,<D-J> :move .+1<CR>==
```

and

```
nnoremap <silent> ,<D-J> :exe ":silent normal move .+1"<CR>==
```

but neither had any effect. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try adding `:<ESC>` at the end.

Comment: Nice workaround! I still get the `:` but it's a big improvement.

Comment: That's strange. `:nnoremap <silent> <C-J> :move .+1<CR>==` is silent for me, as expected. Is it perhaps to do with `<D-...>`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried these mappings to move up with control k and down with control j using visual mode for moving multiple lines:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-J> :move .+1<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-K> :move .-2<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <C-J> :move '>+1<CR>:normal gv<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <C-K> :move '<-2<CR>:normal gv<CR>
```